# How to update $scope with every loop of a $timeout with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a function that runs in the background and takes a long time and I want to update the user of my webpage about progress as it's going. I have a bit of angular that asks the results/[jobID] page what the progress is and that successfully returns the progress.

It runs every 2 seconds and the $log.log(data,status) works, so I see "10%", "30%" etc in the logs, but my {{progress}} variable on the page only updates when the job is complete (ie. triggers the else if (status === 200) loop).

How can I get the $scope.progress to update {{progress}} on every run of poller()?

```
function getProgress(jobID) {

    var timeout = '';

    var poller = function() {
        $http.get('/results/'+jobID).
        success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
            if(status === 202) { // This logs, but doesn't change {{progress}}
                $log.log(data, status);
                $scope.progress = data;
            } else if (status === 200) { // This logs and changes {{progress}}
                $log.log(data);
                $scope.progress = data;
                $timeout.cancel(timeout);
                return false;
            }
            // continue to call the poller() function every 2 seconds
            // until the timeout is cancelled
            timeout = $timeout(poller,2000);
        }).
        error(function(error) {
            $log.log(error);
        });
    };
    poller();
}

getProgress(1234) //is called by another function on form submit
```

If relevant I'm using flask & python code to make the actual pages

Comment: You can use `$scope.$apply` or `$scope.$digest`, here is nice article about differences between them: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: I tried that, putting $scope.$apply(); just before the if statement close bracket and  and got the error:
angular.js:12722 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Edit:typo

Comment: You should add it after `$scope.progress = data;`. Also this method can throw an error if other digest is in progress. You can avoid that by putting `$scope.$apply` in `try-catch` block.

Comment: That's what I meant by just before the if statement close bracket, apologies if that wasn't clear.

Is angular wrapping the function poller() in a digest cycle and the function doesn't end until after status === 200 (ie. the return false; line), so I can't call $scope.$apply() from inside the function?

Comment: Sorry, I actually read it wrong. You should be able to always call `$scope.$apply` inside of a function, the problem `$digest already in progress` shows up when you try to refresh the scope at the same time, when Angular does. Please let me know if putting `$scope.$apply` inside of a `try-catch` block helped.

Comment: I have no idea why that worked - it seems to be running both parts of the try-catch block? But it did work and I've put the working code below for anyone else to see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Faustyn Piechowiak, working answer here:

```
function getProgress(jobID) {
    var timeout = '';
    var poller = function() {
        $http.get('/results/'+jobID).
        success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
            if(status === 202) { // This logs, but doesn't change {{progress}}
                $log.log(data, status);
                $scope.progress = data;
                $scope.comment = data;
                try { // This updates the scope
                    $scope.apply;
                }
                catch(err) { // This also runs
                    $log.log("didn't apply")
                }

            } else if (status === 200) { // This logs, and changes {{progress}}
                $log.log(data);
                $scope.progress = data;
                $timeout.cancel(timeout);
                return false;
            }
            // continue to call the poller() function every 2 seconds
            // until the timeout is cancelled
            timeout = $timeout(poller,2000, true);
        }).
        error(function(error) {
            $log.log(error);
        });
    };
    poller();
}

getProgress(1234) //is called by another function on form submit
```